# Why I couldn't execute these examples from Python

Tags: python, windows, time

I am reading Python 3.7 documentation about timeit, but when I try the examples in the [Examples](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html#examples) section it get errors (see below):

```
python -m timeit -s 'text = "sample string"; char = "g"'  'char in text'
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\timeit.py", line 374, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\timeit.py", line 313, in main
    t = Timer(stmt, setup, timer)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\timeit.py", line 109, in __init__
    compile(setup, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 1
    'text
        ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I am running Python 3.7.3 on Windows 7. (I tested it also on Window 10: cmd & powershell)

Why I am getting that error?

**EDIT**: The command above works fine when I execute it on msys2 or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Just quoting issue. Same issue here:

```
python -m timeit -s 'text = "sample string"; char = "g"'  'char in text'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\timeit.py", line 374, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\timeit.py", line 313, in main
    t = Timer(stmt, setup, timer)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\timeit.py", line 109, in __init__
    compile(setup, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 1
    'text
        ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Change it to:

```
python -m timeit -s "text = 'sample string'; char = 'g' 'char in text'"
20000000 loops, best of 5: 8.62 nsec per loop
```

Comment: Could be a locale issue (just shooting blanks here)

Comment: Because in Windows double quote can be used to specify string and single quote can't. In your first example 'text is a first string and = is a second, etc.

Comment: So, there is a problem in the example given in the python documentation that should be reported.

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician, in CMD, quoting a string with double quotes escapes special characters, except for "%". But the shell in Windows has nothing to do with parsing the command line of a program, unlike Unix. That's up to each individual program. The VC++ rules for parsing `argv` for `main` and WINAPI `CommandLineToArgvW` are the most common, and these rules treat a single quote as just another character. Some programs do have custom parsing that supports single-quoted strings in cases, such as schtasks.exe and even python.exe. But that's usually internal to a parsed `argv` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code locally without issue:

```
> python -m timeit -s 'text = "sample string"; char = "g"'  'char in text'
10000000 loops, best of 5: 31.6 nsec per loop
```

Given this part of your error message: `'text`, I'm guessing that when you tried to run the command, you did not get the last single-quote at the end of the `'char in text'`.